# Arduino IDE error when trying to connect esp8266 to firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide

hello guys i was trying to connect my project to firebase as showed in this video https://youtu.be/Xj1kuApmRCw
but got this erorrs:

```
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\Firebase.cpp: In member function 'int FirebaseRequest::sendRequest(const string&, const string&, char*, const string&, const string&)':
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\Firebase.cpp:78:1: error: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Werror=return-type]
   78 | }
      | ^
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\Firebase.cpp: In member function 'void FirebaseStream::startStreaming(const string&, const string&, const string&)':
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\Firebase.cpp:91:16: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
   91 |   analyzeError("STREAM", status, path_with_auth);
      |                ^~~~~~~~
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp: In member function 'virtual void FirebaseHttpClientEsp8266::begin(const string&)':
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:47:50: error: no matching function for call to 'begin(const char*, const char [60])'
   47 |     http_.begin(url.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);
      |                                                  ^
In file included from d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:9:
C:\Users\NyK\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:166:10: note: candidate: 'bool HTTPClient::begin(String, uint16_t, String)' (near match)
  166 |     bool begin(String host, uint16_t port, String uri = "/")  __attribute__ ((error("obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClient, host, port, uri)")));
      |          ^~~~~
C:\Users\NyK\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:166:10: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:47:30: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} [-fpermissive]
   47 |     http_.begin(url.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                              |
      |                              const char*
In file included from d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:9:
C:\Users\NyK\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:167:10: note: candidate: 'bool HTTPClient::begin(String, const uint8_t*)' (near match)
  167 |     bool begin(String url, const uint8_t httpsFingerprint[20])  __attribute__ ((error("obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClientSecure, ...)")));
      |          ^~~~~
C:\Users\NyK\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:167:10: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:47:30: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t*' {aka 'const unsigned char*'} [-fpermissive]
   47 |     http_.begin(url.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                              |
      |                              const char*
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp: In member function 'virtual void FirebaseHttpClientEsp8266::begin(const string&, const string&)':
d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:51:60: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'const uint8_t*' {aka 'const unsigned char*'} [-fpermissive]
   51 |     http_.begin(host.c_str(), kFirebasePort, path.c_str(), kFirebaseFingerprint);
      |                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                            |
      |                                                            const char*
In file included from d:\Kuliah\Mata Kuliah\Internet of Things\Arduino\libraries\FirebaseArduino\src\FirebaseHttpClient_Esp8266.cpp:9:
C:\Users\NyK\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.2\libraries\ESP8266HTTPClient\src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h:168:70: note:   initializing argument 4 of 'bool HTTPClient::begin(String, uint16_t, String, const uint8_t*)'
  168 |     bool begin(String host, uint16_t port, String uri, const uint8_t httpsFingerprint[20])  __attribute__ ((error("obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClientSecure, ...)")));
      |                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus.exe: some warnings being treated as errors

exit status 1

Compilation error: exit status 1
```

i've installed the latest version of esp8266 and **"Firebase Arduino Client Library for ESP8266 By Mobitz"** but the error still occured. please help

here's my full code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include<DHT.h>

#define FIREBASE_HOST "*****firebaseio.com"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "*****UKBpSMo07nUT8ZWYS9"

#define WIFI_SSID "******"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "******"

#define DHTPIN D5
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

bool light;
bool fan;

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 10000;

void setup() {
  pinMode(D1, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(500);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID,WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.println("Connecting..");
  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST,FIREBASE_AUTH);
  dht.begin();

  delay(2000);
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void readDatas(){
  float h=dht.readHumidity();
  float t=dht.readTemperature(); 

  Firebase.setFloat("Data/Temperature:",t);
  Firebase.setFloat("Data/Humidity:",h); 
}

void loop() {
  light = Firebase.getBool("LightStates/switch");
  Serial.println(light);
  if(light==true){
    digitalWrite(D6, HIGH);
  }
  if(light==false){
    digitalWrite(D6, LOW);
  }

  fan = Firebase.getBool("FanStates/switch");
  Serial.println(fan);
  if(fan==true){
    digitalWrite(D7, HIGH);
  }
  if(fan==false){
    digitalWrite(D7, LOW);
  }

  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if(currentMillis-previousMillis>=interval){
    readDatas();
    previousMillis=currentMillis;
  }

}
```

and here is the screenshot of my firebase for better understanding:

[image]

Comment: From the README of [FirebaseArduino](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino), "This repository is no longer under active development. No new features will be added and issues are not actively triaged.", the library has 191 issues with 23 pull requests and has never been updated for the past 3 years indicated that the library is dead and outdated. Find a new library.

Comment: i have two option: firebase arduino master and Firebase Arduino Client Library for ESP8266 By Mobitz. should i use the : firebase arduino master??

Comment: Asking for recommendation is off topic. It is your choice, and it cost nothing to try.

Comment: i've tried both and got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by downgrading my esp8266 version to 2.7